# How to expand DIV element according to sibling DIV's and container

Tags: css, html

I am trying to do something very simple but I could not do it for 2 days now.

I have this simple HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
            }            
            .container
            {
                position:relative;    
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .header
            {
                height: 180px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
            .content
            {
                height:100%;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #00f;
            }
            .footer
            {
                height: 72px;
                position:absolute;
                bottom:0;
                width:100%; 
            }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">Some header</div>        
            <div class="content">Some content...</div>
            <div class="footer">Some footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you see, I only want the footer to be placed at the bottom of the screen. The problem is that middle div expands to occupy even the footer space. When I remove height: 100% in .content, the middle div does not expand.

I have followed a lot of suggestions and even suggestions from this forum, but with no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: I am confused, by what you have, the content div only goes down to the footer div. http://jsfiddle.net/j93be/

Comment: No it does not, it goes under the footer, you are covering it with the color red :D

Comment: If you use display:inline-block; it will not go into the footer

Comment: Add padding-bottom to your content equal to the height of your footer.

Comment: @Keith yes, ut I don't want it covers footer. inline-block did not work

Comment: @ValiD Color blue.. just to see if it covers

Comment: @Diodeus it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/GSHmn/2/) see if it comes close to what you need.

I changed you .content class to:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00f;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px; /*change according to .header height*/
    bottom: 72px; /*change according to .footer height*/
}
```